# How can I store inputted information in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to ask the user for a student and their corresponding ID number, adding them to the dictionary. But if the user wants to add another student, I'm not sure how to add to the dictionary instead of replacing the other student. Currently, my code replaces the previous student instead of adding another key and item to the database of students. How can I add another student and their ID to the database/dictionary?

```
while input("Would you like to add a student? ") == "yes":
    name = input("What is the student's name?: ")
    ID = input("What is the student's ID?: ")
    nameID = {ID: name}
    for ID in nameID.keys():
        print(nameID)
else:
    print(nameID)
```

Comment: Just checking - did you see the answers? Do they help? If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are not getting the expected output is every time you create a new student you also create a new dict. Therefore, if you just append the student to an existing dict you will avoid the problem your are having.

```
nameID = {}

while input("Would you like to add a student? ") == "yes":
    name = input("What is the student's name?: ")
    ID = input("What is the student's ID?: ")
    nameID[ID] = name
    for ID in nameID.keys():
        print(ID)
else:
    print(nameID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
nameID = {ID: name}
```

*creates* a dictionary, again and again, inside that loop. Create an empty dictionary

```
nameID = {}
```

first, and then add items to it inside the loop:

```
nameID[ID] = name
```

You also don't need to loop over `nameID.keys()` to print them. You probably meant

```
for id in nameID:
    print (id,nameID[id])
```